better do something in case you’re a target for a missile

Looking back almost 35 years later, however Angus confessed to Rolling Stone how, without that suit, "I would never had made effort to get out there and have a presence, I was a lot more shy before that. I would stand back and play. But the suits pull me".


Up to that point he’d just stand there and play, like the rest of us,’
recalled Malcolm. ‘But as soon as he put on that school uniform he became
a monster. Of course, they jeered and whistled when he walked on – these
places you’re playing to men’s men – but as soon as he struck up, the looks on their faces changed.’ Once it became an established part of their act, said Malcolm, and Angus began jumping offstage and spinning on his back on the floor, or leaping up onto tables, ‘drinks would be going over and more drinks being bought so the club owner loved us’. ‘I was always a bit shy, but when I put the suit on I thought, well, you’d better do something in case you’re a target for a missile!’ Angus recalled

Mick Wall, "Hell Ain't A Bad Place To Be".
Could you please explain the bolded text - I get the words but can't get the meaning.

I feel sure there are more appropriate sayings, but perhaps "It's better to go out with a bang than a whimper." Or "I'd rather die on my feet than live on my knees." – Emiliano Zapata. "Do not go gentle into that good night. Rage, rage against the dying of the light." – Dylan Thomas

Or if it is comedy – "put a paper bag over your head". Do you get it? Live life to the full.

Can you explain the context? I'm guessing Angus is an exotic dancer who dresses up in a school uniform?

I tried googling this, it's the name of an AC/DC song. But when I look up the lyrics I don't find anything like this.

Or perhaps he means "if you are a missile target, better make a target that is worth hitting."

Yes, he dresses in school uniforms while playing onstage.

I added the paragraph preceding the OP excerpt.  As the scene took place in 1974 during the cold war, the mentioned "missile"  might be a nuclear-armed ballistic missile, what may confirm @WeatherVane interpretation : Live life to the full before dying.

If you happen to be a target for a missile (because you’re wearing a school boy uniform in a manly crowd), what are you going to do to avoid the missile? Jump offstage and spin on your back on the floor or leap up onto tables...

I think "missile" is more likely to mean a beer bottle or glass. Note the jeering and whistling (in disapproval).


well, you’d better do something in case you’re a target for a missile!’ Angus recalled

Well, you’d better perform some distracting actions in case someone throws something at you!’ Angus recalled.

He talks about getting abuse when going onstage ("they jeered and whistled"), and it's traditionally common in rougher bars and venues for people to throw things at bands (see the movie Blues Brothers for an extreme example), so this is definitely the most likely explanation
